# SplitRatio results with sample.split (caTools)

Tags: r

The `SplitRatio` argument does not behave like I would expect it to.

For example, if the `SplitRatio` is `0.5`, I would expect `50% TRUE` and `50% FALSE` assignments.

However, when running the code below on a vector of length 20 I would expect 10 TRUE assignment but I frequently get results like 13 or 14.

Why is that?

```
vec <- sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
length(vec)
split <- sample.split(vec, SplitRatio = 0.5)
vec.split <- subset(vec, split == TRUE)
length(vec.split)
[1] 13
```